# Failed to create the Java Virtual Machine error with JETL v7.1.1 on mac Ventura

Tags: java, talend, jasperserver

I am trying to setup JETL-20181026_1147-V7.1.1 on my Mac M1 Ventura.
When I double click on the Aplication (JETL-macosx-cocoa -- inside the  JETL-20181026_1147-V7.1.1 folder), I end up getting the alert:

'Failed to create the Java Virtual Machine'

I have tried updating the configuration to use java jdk1.8.0_151.jdk (also tried jdk1.8.0_361.jdk):

Steps:

Right click on the application(JETL-macosx-cocoa) > Show Package Contents > Dbl click on Contents > Open the info.plist.
Add the following to point to a specific version of Java:

```
    <array>
        <string>-vm</string>
        <string>/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_151.jdk/Contents/Home</string>
    </array>
```

I also tried updating the memory parameters in ETL-macosx-cocoa.ini

```
-Xms128M
-Xmx512M
```

I wonder if there is also a compatibility issue with Mac M1 ventura, but cannot say for sure. If anyone has come across the same issue, and can help with how did they go about resolving it, it would help.

Answer (score 0):

Your version of JETL, whatever it is, is from 2018, which means that the JDK version it ships with does not support macOS running on an ARM CPU.

Comment: thanks for your response. Is there a compatibility matrix I can look for, where I can check what version suits my system. I am working with Mac M1, and  java 1.8.